# Return MyNestedClass<K> when MyNestedClass is not MyNestedClass<K>?

Tags: c#, .net

Breaking down the MS RBTree (an internal .Net abstract class), I have discovered that one method returns `TreePage<K>`:

```
private TreePage<K> AllocPage(int size)
{
    ...
}
```

Within the method, variables are declared as TreePage...but the class is not defined that way:

```
private sealed class TreePage
{
    ...
}
```

Yet, when I mimic the code and definition using .Net 2010 (Express), I cannot do this:

> Error:     The non-generic type
>   'RBTree.TreePage' cannot be used
>   with type arguments

So, is there an extension method that I can't find? Is there something MS is doing that we just don't get to see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare a class nested in a generic class

```
class Foo<T>
{
    class Bar
    {
    }
}
```

this gets compiled to a class

```
Foo<T>
```

and a class

```
Foo+Bar<T>
```

Bar is generic, because it is nested in the generic class Foo. But the type parameter declaration is not repeated in C# (where you refer to the class as Foo<T>.Bar).

I noticed that Reflector shows the generic type parameter for classes nested in generic types, even if they don't have declared any type parameters directly. That's a bug. You need to fix the code when copy it straight out of Reflector.

Comment: so, Reflector is showing me TreePage<K>...what you're saying is, then, that I should remove any generic <K> type arguments and it should be okay?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this addresses the OP's question though?  (I think Logan nailed it.)

Comment: @dboarman: if you got your code from Reflector and there is no generic TreePage to be found, then, yes, you've stumpled upon a bug and you need to remove the <K>.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually less complicated than you might imagine. `Klass` and `Klass<T>` are two completely different types. To wit:

```
  class A
  {
  }

  class A<T>
  {}

  class Program
  {
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
      A a = new A();
      A<int> generic_a = new A<int>();
    }
  }
```

There's another `TreePage<T>` floating around there somewhere.

Comment: However, Reflector is not seeing 2 classes. When I search for `TreePage`, it responds with `TreePage<K>`. When I select to disassemble this class, it is defined exactly as I showed in my question.

Comment: @dboarman I didn't know you were using reflector (you didn't mention that in your question), I assumed you were looking at source. As dtb mentioned, reflector does have bugs.

Comment: This would not work the way it is intended. For instance, I would not be able to add objects of type `A` to an `A<K> []` array.

Comment: @Logan: not to be terse, but how else would I be able to break *'down the MS RBTree (an internal .Net abstract class)'* as I stated in the first line of my question? ;)

Comment: Intended by who? I was merely explaining how you could have code like `class X { X<T> Foo() { ... } }`. Of course you didn't actually have code like that. You can always look at the CIL instead of the reconstructed C#, that will never lie to you (even in cases where the "lying" isn't a bug, like when a feature that isn't present in C# was used like VB.NET's When on catch statements).